# Не устанавливаются модули Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

Всем привет, у меня никак не получается установить **АБСОЛЮТНО никакие** модули. Пробовал переустанавливать сам Node.JS, но увы, ничего не решилось. Надеюсь, кто-нибудь поможет решить эту проблему

```
PS C:\Users\audio\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\TOP SECRET NATO FILES> npm install canvas
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Users\\audio\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\TOP SECRET NATO FILES\\node_modules\\are-we-there-yet',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\audio\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\TOP SECRET NATO FILES\node_modules\are-we-there-yet\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\internal\streams'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\audio\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\TOP SECRET NATO FILES\\node_modules\\are-we-there-yet\\node_modules\\readable-stream\\lib\\internal\\streams'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ]
npm WARN cleanup ]
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\audio\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\TOP SECRET NATO FILES\node_modules\canvas
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --update-binary
npm ERR! Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --update-binary --module=C:\Users\audio\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\TOP SECRET NATO FILES\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=C:\Users\audio\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\TOP SECRET NATO FILES\node_modules\canvas\build\Release --napi_version=9 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v120' (1)       
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.11
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@21.5.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! (node:596) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.11.2/canvas-v2.11.2-node-v120-win32-unknown-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.11.2/canvas-v2.11.2-node-v120-win32-unknown-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for canvas@2.11.2 and node@21.5.0 (node-v120 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.11.2/canvas-v2.11.2-node-v120-win32-unknown-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@10.0.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@21.5.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@10.0.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@21.5.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.12.1 found at "C:\Python312\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer, try re-running with '--loglevel silly' for more details
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2015 as it is only supported up to Node.js 18
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:113:11)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:69:17)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at async createBuildDir (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:69:26)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at async run (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js:81:18)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22631
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--update-binary" "--module=C:\\Users\\audio\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\TOP SECRET NATO FILES\\node_modules\\canvas\\build\\Release\\canvas.node" "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\audio\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\TOP SECRET NATO FILES\\node_modules\\canvas\\build\\Release" "--napi_version=9" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v120"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\audio\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\TOP SECRET NATO FILES\node_modules\canvas
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v21.5.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v10.0.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --update-binary --module=C:\Users\audio\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\TOP SECRET NATO FILES\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=C:\Users\audio\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\TOP SECRET NATO FILES\node_modules\canvas\build\Release --napi_version=9 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v120' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\audio\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\TOP SECRET NATO FILES\node_modules\@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:89:23)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:519:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:305:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22631
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\audio\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\TOP SECRET NATO FILES\\node_modules\\@mapbox\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--update-binary"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\audio\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\TOP SECRET NATO FILES\node_modules\canvas
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v21.5.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.11
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\audio\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-12-27T10_29_00_949Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: А что Вы такое пытаетесь установить? Там куча `deprecated`, тот же [Request](https://github.com/request/request) не обновлялся 5 лет, а актуальная версия `uuid` -- 9.0.1, а у Вас 3.4.0, я молчу о том что некоторые пекеджи просто не найдены и к примеру `Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use`, читайте ошибки. Даже если упустить не найденные пакеты, то вероятнее всего все это не будет работать на актуальной версии `Node.js`.

Comment: Пытаюсь установить Canvas. Самое смешное в том, что на другом ПК всё функционирует отлично и там стоит такая же версия Node.JS, какая у меня

Comment: вам нужно: 1) удалить папку node_modules в проекте и установить пакеты заново npm i 2) установить Visual Studio по инструкции https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows 3) устанавливать canvas

Comment: энивей я не могу установить пакеты нода, оно так же срёт ошибками в терминал

Comment: перенесите разработку в какое-то место, где в пути не будет ни пробелов ни русских букв `Рабочий стол\TOP SECRET NATO FILES`. например, 'c:\dev\nato'

Comment: C:\TOP SECRET NATO FILES
Проблема осталась

Comment: К сожалению, люди не умеют писать `Batchfile` (по `GitHub` или `winbatch` в простонародии; касается ли это `node-pre-gyp` или `npx`? <- ритор.; касается). А также не умеют делать "пути к объектам файловой системы" в кавычках при вызове `cmd`. У меня такая же проблема с многострадальным `node-pre-gyp` из-за `&` в путях. (см. `mklink`, "нормальны пути" (*никто не мешает сделать `npm install ...` в папку с нормальными путями и скопировать `node_modules` в папку без нормальных путей <- `bat-рецепты с npm-вызовом из-под временной win:net share / mklink опускаются`*) и перепись `Batchfile`) К слову,